# Setup.exe build from azure pipelines prompts for .NET framework 4.7.2 on every run

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, publish, setup.exe

We are trying to generate a click once application using azure devops pipelines.

During this, we publish the project to create a setup.exe. All the pre-requisites required are ticked, the project builds and publishes the setup.exe without any issues.

However, every time the setup.exe is run we see the prompt in Image 1.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc2Y0.png)

We have ensured the installURL is correct, and the .NET Framework 4.7.2 is on the build machine and install machine.

When we publish the project in visual studio, the setup.exe does not show this prompt.

Does anyone have any idea how to stop this prompt showing or what we could try next?

Comment: Can you run to run the setup.exe file with administrator privilege to see if the prompt still comes out?

Comment: I still get the same prompt when running in administrator and when trying the compatibility wizard.

Answer (score 0):

In your Visual Studio build task in your pipeline, make sure you have Visual Studio 2019 selected due to a bug in earlier versions of VS.

[image]
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/743594/dotnetfx472-and-dotnetfx48-not-finding-information.html

Comment: Have tried changing all the build tasks to make sure they are running VS 2019 but still same issue.